# I designed a simple webpage using bootstrap4, but whatever I try I couldn't make it responsive. Can anyone help me?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am just still a novice in web development fundamentals. Following are my JavaScript, CSS and HTML codes. I tried to use bootstrap 4 to make my page responsive, but I couldn't minimize my content to different devices using the d-flex(I have attached an image for reference too). Can anyone point out where am I going wrong? 
My page is about generating a background using the linear-gradient property of CSS along with a random color combination generator button. I used 3 color inputs for background(2) and font-text(1).

```js
var css = document.querySelector("h3");
var color1 = document.querySelector(".color1");
var color2 = document.querySelector(".color2");
var body = document.getElementById("gradient");
var textColor = document.querySelector(".textcolor");
var randomColorGenerator = document.getElementById("randomgen");

setGradient();

function setTextColor() {
 body.style.color = textColor.value;
}

function setGradient() {
 body.style.background = 
 "linear-gradient(to right, " 
 + color1.value 
 + ", " 
 + color2.value 
 + ")";
    body.style.backgroundAttachment = "fixed";


 css.textContent = body.style.background + ";";
}

function randomColor() {
  var hex = "#" + Math.floor(Math.random()*16777216).toString(16);
  return hex
}

function generateRandomColorButton() {
  color1.value = randomColor();
  color2.value = randomColor();

  setGradient();
}

color1.addEventListener("input", setGradient);

color2.addEventListener("input", setGradient);

textColor.addEventListener("input", setTextColor);

randomColorGenerator.addEventListener("click", generateRandomColorButton);
```

```css
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
 min-height: 100%;
 background: linear-gradient(to right, red, yellow);
    background-attachment: fixed;    
}


h1 {
    font: 600 3.5em 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: .5em;
    
}

.color1, .color2, .textcolor {
    cursor: pointer;
}
h2 {
    font: 500 2em 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: .25em;
    font-variant: small-caps;
}
.labelcolor {
    font: 800 1em 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    letter-spacing: 0.25em;
}
h3 {
 font: 900 1em 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    text-transform: none;
    letter-spacing: 0.01em;

}

.btn{
    padding: 10px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-variant: small-caps;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Gradient Background</title>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CDN -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <!-- Animate.css stylesheet -->
    <link
    rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.0.0/animate.min.css"
  />


 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>
<body id="gradient">

 <div class="container d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-center">
 <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
 <header class="text-center col-12"> 
 <br><br><h1 class="animate__animated animate__backInLeft">Background Generator</h1><br><br>
 <label for="color1" class="labelcolor">Color1</label>
 <input class="color1" type="color" name="color1" value="#00ff00">
    <label for="color1" class="labelcolor">Color2 </label>
 <input class="color2" type="color" name="color2" value="#ff0000">
 <label for="textcolor" class="labelcolor">Text Color</label>
 <input type="color" class="textcolor" name="textcolor" value="#000000">
 <br><br><h2>Current CSS Background</h2><br><br>
 <h3></h3><br><br>
 <button id="randomgen" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Random Color Generator</button>
 </header> 
 </div>
 </div>
 <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[Here is a screenshot of how the web page looks on a iphone x](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxW9T.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to decrease the font size of `h1, h2, h3, h4, h5`
it will look fine on mobile

---

**UPDATE**:

you could try this:

1. Change the Bootstrap 4 CDN using this one below. (I got this from official docs of Boostrap 4) .

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

2. Change Jquery and Bootstrap 4 JS using this one

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

3. Change the CSS into:

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, red, yellow) fixed;
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

h2 {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.color1, .color2, .textcolor {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.labelcolor {
    font: 800 1em 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    letter-spacing: 0.25em;
}
h3 {
    font: 900 1em 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    text-transform: none;
    letter-spacing: 0.01em;
}

.btn{
    padding: 10px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-variant: small-caps;
}
```

4. This is the final HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Gradient Background</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.0.0/animate.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body id="gradient">

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                1 of 3
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                2 of 3 (wider)
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                3 of 3
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                1 of 3
            </div>
            <div class="col-5">
                2 of 3 (wider)
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                3 of 3
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-center">
        <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <header class="text-center col-12">
                <br><br><h1 class="animate__animated animate__backInLeft">Background Generator</h1><br><br>
                <label for="color1" class="labelcolor">Color1</label>
                <input class="color1" type="color" name="color1" value="#00ff00">
                <label for="color1" class="labelcolor">Color2 </label>
                <input class="color2" type="color" name="color2" value="#ff0000">
                <label for="textcolor" class="labelcolor">Text Color</label>
                <input type="color" class="textcolor" name="textcolor" value="#000000">
                <br><br><h2>Current CSS Background</h2><br><br>
                <h3></h3><br><br>
                <button id="randomgen" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Random Color Generator</button>
            </header>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

What I change is several things:

1. Remove Integrity and Anonymous - if you just develop this for local
   development you don't need it. For Production usage, you could
   download the scripts and styles.
2. Clean up the CSS
3. Add some bootstrap `row` and `col` to proofing the responsiveness

Hope this helps~

Comment: It's not what I desired on my webpage, but even if I reduced the font size it's not responsive on mobile devices.

Comment: @nmudd037 I've edited my answer, you could try that ya~

Comment: Thank-you! for your help. It worked really well, what's the difference by using the integrity and anonymous from the bootstrap and not?

Comment: Well, I even tried the media query option by setting a max-width and it worked out well too.
@media  (max-width: 600px) { ...}

Comment: @nmudd037its for security purpose that you are loading the correct data (like a checksum), but I think the problem is, you load the scripts and styles not from official docs because the domain is different

You are using `https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrxxxxxx`
meanwhile, I try the `https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstr`

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this

```
    <header class="text-center col-12 col-sm-11">
```

here col-12 and col-sm-11 are the bootstrap grid points which tell us about the build layouts of all shapes and sizes.

You can learn them from here : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/

Comment: Even, when I changed the grid points as you mentioned I couldn't see any considerable change in the layout.

Comment: can you describe in detail, what you want?  If you want your font size to reduce when it is on mobile-device then you might need to use media query also.

Comment: I just want my web page to adjust to the mobile screen size, is there any option for me to do that with or without the help of media queries. I understood the concept of media queries but how should I write the code for different screen sizes that I didn't get it, can you give me a brief explanation?
I attached an image to the original question you can have a look at it, the content is not adjusted to the screen size of different devices.

Comment: well then my advice will also be to learn to use the bootstrap grid in your code, It works for me, You need to give a definite structure for your Html code using container, row and column classes. It will be better if you prefer to bootstrap documentation, it will provide you with all the necessary information.

Comment: Thank-you! for your suggestions and insights.I tried the media query option by setting a max-width and it worked out for me.